# Encode url string

Tags: ios, objective-c, urlencode

I'm trying to encode url string using Objective-c

```
// 1. Get string
char res = ((char)(400));
NSString *unencodedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",res];

// 2. Encode string
static NSString *escape = @":/?&=;+!@#$()',*[]";
NSString *result = (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                        NULL,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                                        NULL,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)escape,
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
// result = %C2%90
```

But result is not that I expect. Because I get `%C6%90` using other programming languages.

As you see Objective-C result is `%C2%90`, but I expect `%C6%90`.

Where is my error? Am I do something wrong?

Comment: What is your input, what output do you expect?

Comment: he expects the output to match in all cases, @L.B ; also, I'm wondering why Alexander is xor-ing the starting character of "`1`" with "`417`"?

Comment: The input is character with code 400. I expect to get url encoded string `%C6%C90`. Xor-ing removed from question.

Comment: In which part/language you have the problem `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(((char)400).ToString())` returns what you say.

Comment: Objective-C code returns wrong value `%C2%90`. Other languages return `%C6%90`. I can't figure out why is it?

Comment: @Alexander then focus on your `Objective-C code`. I don't know why you tagged it as c#

Comment: @AnthonyKong, No. It's turned out that problem was in getting NSString from char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `NSString *unencodedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",res]` doesn't do what you think it does. `char res` cannot hold a value larger than 128 (256 for `unsigned char`).

```
char res = ((char)(400));
NSString *unencodedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",res];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(unencodedString, @"\xc2\x90", @"");

static NSString *escape = @":/?&=;+!@#$()',*[]";
NSString *result = (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                        NULL,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                                        NULL,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)escape,
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

XCTAssertEqualObjects(result, @"%C2%90", @"");
```

Here is an example which works.

```
NSString *unencodedString = @"Ɛ";

static NSString *escape = @":/?&=;+!@#$()',*[]";
NSString *result = (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                        NULL,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                                        NULL,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)escape,
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
XCTAssertEqualObjects(result, @"%C6%90", @"");
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want a sample like this to work, use `unichar` and `-stringWithCharacters:length:`.

```
unichar res = ((unichar)(400));
NSString *unencodedString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&res length:1];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(unencodedString, @"Ɛ", @"");

static NSString *escape = @":/?&=;+!@#$()',*[]";
NSString *result = (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                        NULL,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)unencodedString,
                                        NULL,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)escape,
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
XCTAssertEqualObjects(result, @"%C6%90", @"");
```

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thank you.

Comment: @Alexander, I updated my answer for a sample which does work.

Comment: @Alexander, one last thing, you can also use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", res]` with a unichar `res`. NOTE: `%C` is a capital C.